# How to open file on local machine from server with JCIFs/SMB

Tags: java, smb, jcifs

How to open a doc or docx file on a local machines sharedrive, but I cannot find a proper method in the samba library to open the file on the local machine. Any ideas?

```
import jcifs.smb.NtlmPasswordAuthentication;
import jcifs.smb.SmbFile;
import jcifs.smb.SmbFileInputStream;
import jcifs.smb.SmbFileOutputStream;
import jcifs.smb.FileUtilityService;
import org.apache.commons.vfs2.operations.FileOperation;


String user = "some_username";
String pass = "some_password";

db.log("Test log");

String filename = "testdoc.docx";
String path = "smb://my_path";

db.log("Path " + path);
try {
    NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(path,     user, pass);
    //FileOperation.openFile(path);
    db.log("Password Authentication Success");
    SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile(path + filename, auth);
  db.log("SMB File is set up");
  //FileOperation.openFile(smbfile);
    //SmbFileOutputStream smbfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(smbFile);
    db.log("Setup the File Output ");

} catch (Exception e) {
    db.log("The error is: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: I'm confused.  If you know the file is local, why not just use `java.io.File`?

Comment: Because I am trying to access them from a web server. The application is running on a web server, and we want something similar to `Desktop.getDesktop.Open()` to occur on our local machine, but that is not supported in our system

Comment: So you want the web application to open a file on the client's machine?  And then do what with it?  Display it to that same client?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want to do

Comment: why not just have your web application give them a link like `file:///path/to/target`?

Comment: I could easily generate a link in the web app to show them, but how would I present a link to them that would open on their machine?

Comment: All links open on the local (client) machine.  `file:///` links will search the local (client) PC's drive for the file, and will not bother the server at all.  That's what they're for.